# How to place a card at the middle of the screen using react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, grid, react-bootstrap

I am creating a Login page.The Login page contains a card which is placed at the centre of the screen.
I am not being able to place the card at centre of the screen and I am stuck in this problem.Please help me out with this.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I have tried doing display: 'flex', flex-direction:'column', align-items: 'centre', but the card is placed at middle of the row and top-most of the screen.

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

please mention with your code and which library used.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

class reactBootstrapCardCenter extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col/>
          <Col>
            <Card style={{marginTop: 50, marginBottom: 50}}>
              <Card.Body>Card at the middle of the screen using react-bootstrap</Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
          <Col/>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default reactBootstrapCardCenter
```